# Using Nodejs or Websocket with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, session, websocket

I need to integrate some realtime widget on my PHP project, like a chat, and update realtime informations fetched from MySQL.

What is the best, fastest one to use ? NodeJS or Websocket (Ratchet, Thruway etc) ?

After some searches, many users share sessions between php and nodejs using redis, but is this fast for many concurrent users for example ?

For PHP WEBSOCKETS side, i found that Thruway is more modern than RATCHET and other solutions, but there no documentation around it ! I found too about wsphp.net, but it's not open source and work only using NGINX, what about apache ?

The things i need:

- I need to push notifications to a specific user to update some infos in the page or make an alert of something happened or changed on their account.
- Need to use php session to manage user datas
- Update realtime datas for all clients instantly once entered by other users.

Please guide me on this.

Comment: "best" without specific measurable requirements and criteria is a purely subjective opinion and generally leads to an off-topic question here (primarily opinion based).

Comment: If it's already a PHP project, thus you presumably already know PHP and its tools and you need to use the PHP session, then it seems the more operative thing for you to figure out is if there's any reason NOT to use PHP?  Both will work fine.

Comment: @jfriend00 I made some searches, and i think redis + php + nodejs is a good solution, better than php websockets for many concurrent users.

Comment: If you found objective information based on some actual measurements that makes for a clear answer, you can post an answer to your own question, but you need to include facts and reasoning, not just opinion.